# How can I get a goroutine's runtime ID?

Tags: go, logging, concurrency, runtime

How can I get a goroutine's runtime ID?

I'm getting interleaved logs from an imported package - one approach would be to add a unique identifier to the logs of each goroutine.

I've found some references to `runtime.GoID`:

```
func worker() {
    id := runtime.GoID()
    log.Println("Goroutine ID:", id)
}
```

But it looks like this is now outdated/has been removed - https://pkg.go.dev/runtime?

Comment: There has never been goroutine scoped identifiers. You must pass any local context you need to the goroutine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go deliberately chooses not to provide an ID since it would encourage worse software and hurt the overall ecosystem: https://go.dev/doc/faq#no_goroutine_id

Generally, the desire to de-anonymize goroutines is a design flaw and is strongly not recommended. There is almost always going to be a much better way to solve the issue at hand. Eg, if you need a unique identifier, it should be passed into the function or potentially via context.Context.

However, internally the runtime needs IDs for the implementation. For educational purposes you can find them with something like:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(goid())

    done := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        fmt.Println(goid())
        done <- struct{}{}
    }()
    go func() {
        fmt.Println(goid())
        done <- struct{}{}
    }()
    <-done
    <-done
}

var (
    goroutinePrefix = []byte("goroutine ")
    errBadStack     = errors.New("invalid runtime.Stack output")
)

// This is terrible, slow, and should never be used.
func goid() (int, error) {
    buf := make([]byte, 32)
    n := runtime.Stack(buf, false)
    buf = buf[:n]
    // goroutine 1 [running]: ...

    buf, ok := bytes.CutPrefix(buf, goroutinePrefix)
    if !ok {
        return 0, errBadStack
    }

    i := bytes.IndexByte(buf, ' ')
    if i < 0 {
        return 0, errBadStack
    }

    return strconv.Atoi(string(buf[:i]))
}
```

Example output:

```
1 <nil>
19 <nil>
18 <nil>
```

They can also be found (less portably) via assembly by accessing the `goid` field in the `g` struct. This is how packages like [github.com/petermattis/goid](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/petermattis/goid) typically do it.

Comment: It's sometimes quite useful to see in which goroutine a log message is printed. Otherwise how is one supposed to detect leaked goroutines?

Comment: Off topic for this question, but leaked goroutines can be found by watching `runtime.NumGoroutine()` over time or reviewing `runtime.GoroutineProfile()` / `runtime.Stack()`.  Application developers should use a meaningful label for logging (eg, RequestID or whatever makes sense - they can choose/implement). The Go FAQ entry linked above goes into more detail. It may seem inconvenient on the surface, but it's a very deliberate decision for the health of the ecosystem based on experience.